# itgencun017: After a fresh Invantive Data Hub install, my batch script isn't working anymore

Tags: invantive-sql, invantive-data-hub

My script wasn't executing correctly, so I took a look at the log file that's also created by the batch script.

It shows the following error:

```
2017-09-05 07:34:24.324 Error itgencun016: Waarschuwing itgenuty427: Een verbinding met de database 'Oracle MySQL\***' kon niet worden opgebouwd als gebruiker '***'.
Verbinding 'Oracle MySQL\***' kan niet worden gevonden.

2017-09-05 07:34:24.324 Error itgencun016: Warning itgenuty427: A connection with the database'Oracle MySQL\***' could not be established as user '***'.
Connection 'Oracle MySQL\***' could not be found.
```

This is my script:

```
local remark local log on connection "Exact Online (REST interface)\Exact Online REST (nl)" user "***" password "***" silent

use ***, ***, ***

local define boekjaar "2016"

select Division bedrijf
,      FinancialPeriod periode
,      Date datum
,      GLAccountCode grootboek
,      Description omschrijving
,      trim(AccountCode) crednummer
,      AmountDC bedrag
from   TransactionLines 
where  FinancialYear = ${boekjaar}
and    GLAccountCode between '***' AND '***'
order 
by     bedrijf
,      datum

local remark export results as "c:\temp\***.csv" format csv

local remark exit 0

local remark Uncomment this part when you have connectivity directly to MySQL.

local memorize results clipboard grootboek 

local log on connection "Oracle MySQL\***" user "***" password "***" silent

local remark truncate table ***

local insert results clipboard grootboek in table ***
```

This used to work before. How would I go around and solve this?

Comment: Please note that the use of an unencrypted password in a 'local log on' is depreciated. In the last release it is no longer available. Use encrypted passwords instead. Generate them using 'local encrypt password' for use on a specific device.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL file contains a command to connect to a MySQL database, but the connection to this database is no longer available in the settings after the fresh install.

This connection should be defined in your `settings.xml` in the `c:\Users\<User>\Invantive` folder (the value of `%USERPROFILE%`).

You could find a 'last working settings file`in the`c:\Users\\Invantive\ Backup` folder.

Use these settings in a new `settings-companyname.xml` that should be put alongside the `settings.xml` file in the `c:\Users\User\Invantive` folder. This way Data Hub will pick up the missing connection, merge it in with `settings.xml` and the batch file should execute once again.

And when you reset or delete `settings.xml`, the additional settings will be merged again.

Make sure you define the right connection path in the batch file.